# Add folder to assets path literaly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

i am trying to add a path to the assets routes for a css folder.

Right now if i either add the path using

```
Rails.application.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "css")
```

i can acces it using 127.0.0.1/assets/somefile.css and this will fetch the file from the folder css that is inside assets but this is not i want to do, what i want is this

127.0.0.1/assets/css/somefile.css

but this gives me an error. How can i route this properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails likes to flatten assets into just `/assets`. You could avoid that by putting the source file into `public/assets/css/`, skipping the Asset Pipeline.

Also keep in mind that in production, anything in `app/assets/*` will be renamed to allow more aggressive caching, e.g. to `/assets/application-sfdalkjsdafljkdsfakldfs.css`. So being picky about how you want to name these files will cause trouble there too.